# payment_method called incorrectly while adding an action to order received emails

Tags: methods, woocommerce, payment

I am using this code to show additional information in the order received emails sent by woocommerce.

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2);

function add_order_email_instructions($order, $sent_to_admin) {

if (!$sent_to_admin) {

    if ( isset( $gateways['cod'] ) == $order->payment_method) {
        // cash on delivery method
        do_action('woocommerce_thankyou_lieferung', $order->get_id());
    } else {
        // other methods (ie credit card)

        do_action('woocommerce_thankyou_lieferung', $order->get_id());
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me the error message

*payment_method was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.*

in the debug.log file

I can not find what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: Try the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2);

function add_order_email_instructions($order, $sent_to_admin) {

if (!$sent_to_admin) {

    if ( isset( $gateways['cod'] ) == $order->get_payment_method()) {
        // cash on delivery method
        do_action('woocommerce_thankyou_lieferung', $order->get_id());
    } else {
        // other methods (ie credit card)

        do_action('woocommerce_thankyou_lieferung', $order->get_id());
    }
  }
}
```